# Dispose `DbContext` after `SaveChangeAsync` in EF core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a question to make sure what I want to do. I know that I should `Dispose` if I want to RollBack Transaction in a request. But my question is that is it necessary to use `Dispose` for DbContext after `SaveChangeAsync()` or it would be done automatically after request is done?

**UPDATE:**
I use Unit of Work in Repository pattern so I have a UnitOfWork class that has an interface and it has all the **Repository** of my entities and a private readonly instance of DbContext :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;  
            public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Then I add an instance of IUnitOfWork per request and define it in the constructor.

Comment: How do you use `DbContext`? Show code.

Comment: @DavidG It was my typing error, Thank you for your mention

Comment: If you are using dependency injection (which you absolutely should) then that will handle the disposing for you. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#overview-of-dependency-injection

Comment: The whole point of disposing is so that changes are discarded if there's any kind of problem. That's why all tutorials that don't use DI create DbContext or connection instances in `using` clauses. A DbContext **is** a Unit-of-Work already, caching all changes in memory. It doesn't even have a database connection until you call `SaveChanges`, at which point a connection is used, all changes are persisted in a single db transaction, and everything is closed again

Comment: If you want your custom Unit-of-Work to work as well as DbContext does it will have to implement IDisposeable too and call `_db.Dispose()`. A DbContext is already an implementation of UoW and a multi-entity Repository. A DbSet is already an implementation of a single-entity Repository.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I update my Question for more detail.

Comment: @DavidG I read the document related what you said and  I use DI for `UnitOfWork` class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your comment was so helpful. So I have to add IDisposable to my UnitOfWork class and use it after all end-up requests, is it true?

Comment: It doesn't matter, DI will handle the UoW and the DbContext